# Rotated logs with newsyslog, but PostgreSQL doesn't write to new one until I restart it

Tags: homebrew, postgresql, macos

I installed PostgreSQL on my mac using homebrew and it's been working great. I recently increased the amount of logging going on because I need to use pgbadger, so naturally I set up log rotation using newsyslog. But when it rotates the log, PostgreSQL doesn't start logging to it until I restart it. The new log file just has this message:

```
Feb  5 10:30:00 MacBook-Pro newsyslog[89092]: logfile turned over due to size>4096K
```

Is there something I can do to either newsyslog or postgres to make it continue logging after rotating the log file?

Comment: System logs are natively rotated in macOS.  Try disabling newsyslog.

Comment: @Allan newsyslog is how it natively rotates the logs.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be setup

Comment: It does if you installed with homebrew, because homebrew installed postgresql logs go to /usr/local/var/log.